# How do I re-use an asyncio event loop in Python?

Tags: python, concurrency, python-asyncio, aiohttp, event-loop

I have an object class with multiple functions in it. The library I am using (pymyq / aiohttp) requires its function calls to be `await`ed, which I need to do in two separate functions.

```
class MyObject:
    
    def login():
        asyncio.run(login_coroutine())
        ...
    
    def set_state():
        asyncio.run(set_coroutine())
        ...

async def login_coroutine():
    await pymyq.login(...)

async def set_coroutine():
    await device.open(...)
```

If I call `login()` and `set_state()` in the same Python process, the one I call second, gives an error from aiohttp: `RuntimeError: Session is closed`.

I can only assume I'm using asyncio incorrectly - but how can I utilize asyncio to `await` at two different points in my program? Two different event loops? Every example I've found online would include both calls in one function, but this is a running Flask app where either `login()` or `set_state()` could be called at any time.

Comment: You'll want to use things like `asyncio.get_event_loop` and `loop.run_until_complete`. Although as written, this code doesn't behind from asyncio. You might be better off writing purely synchronous code since that's how it's going to run anyway.

Comment: @dirn i'd love to avoid async code altogether, but the library I need to use, pyMyQ, requires use of asyncio. Any idea why the second function call errors out when doing `asyncio.new_event_loop().run_until_complete(...)` for both of them? How can two different loops, each closing after finishing out, affect each other?

Comment: `new_event_loop`, just like `run` creates a new event loop. If you want you reuse the loop, `get_event_loop` is what you need. You could also pass the loop to `MyObject` and store it as `self.loop`.